# modifying List of complex types EF6 MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

assuming I have the following:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual List<LastName> LastName { get; set; }
    }

 public class LastName
    {
        public int LastNameID { get; set; }
        public new string Value1 { get; set; }
    }
```

and I have an index page where the model is a list of employees with the following:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
//link to Edit page where I can modify the last names in the list
@Html.ActionLink(item.LastName[someIndex], "Edit", new { id = item.EmployeeID })
```

and in the controller I have

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Employee employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
            if (employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(employee);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               //EXCEPTION HERE - 
                db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(employee);
        }
```

and an edit view like this

```
@model Testing123.Models.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LastName";
}

<h2>Last Names</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.LastName.Count; i ++)
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName[i].Value1)

                   //ADDED HIDDEN FOR HERE**** Throwing new exception, see below
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LastName[i].LastNameID)


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

When I submit this edit form, it gives me an exception :

Attaching an entity of type 'Testing123.Models.LastName' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate

Is this the correct way of modifying the List of LastName complex type object? 
meaning, If have 4 last names already, and I enter this view, with the text boxes, and each last name is displayed in a text box, and I change the value in the text box, will this update the last names on form submitting?

***EDIT***

After adding the HiddenFor helper, I'm getting the following exception now on db.saveChanges

Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful to see where the exception is coming from (i.e. stack trace), but in the absence of that there are a few things I'd point out.

1. In the Edit action you check if `employee` is null after you've already used it to get the `LastName` property.
2. The Edit view does not (or didn't before the edit) provide any mechanism to link the text boxes it generates back to the model. You should use the [`Html.TextBoxFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) rather than `Html.TextBox`. Also you need to have the `LastNameId` referenced in an `Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LastName[i].LastNameId)` (inside the loop, obviously) and the `EmployeeId` and `FirstName` in `Html.HiddenFor` entries (outside the loop) so that when the employee is posted back all of the properties on it and its child collection are round-tripped back to the server.
3. `LastName` (the type) is not a complex type because it doesn't have a `[ComplexType]` attribute and it does have a column that will be inferred as the primary key of the table. This distinction between complex types and normal EF entities is probably not important to answering the question, though. Have a look at [this article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/making-complex-types-useful.aspx) for more information.

Comment: thanks for the answer and pointing those things out, your first point, I didn't realize that, most of that code is auto-generated, so I didn't put much thought into getting the LastName property. This is just too frustrating that I'm just trying anything to get it to work..

Comment: also, exceptions are coming from db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified; I don't know what to put in the Entry

Comment: Return the employee as the model in the Edit view, even though you're only going to allow editing of LastName. You would then loop through Model.LastName using TextBoxFor. In the POST for the edit you would then be taking an Employee as an argment, and the db.Entry would not fail.

Comment: ok, I'm trying now, I'll let you know how it goes, thanks for the response!

Comment: when I'm using textboxfor how do I make it so that the current value for the LastName[i] is displayed in the text box before I edit it? also, do I need to add any specific html attributes for the textboxfor?

Comment: exception: Attaching an entity of type 'Testing123.Models.LastName' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate

Comment: this is after I've changed the model of the edit view to be Models.Employee and changed the action method to take an Employee argument, will update my code to show you what I have

Comment: Use Html.HiddenFor to put the ID into the form for each row. Then you'll have a pair of inputs (one hidden, with the ID, and one a text box with the name) for each LastName in the collection.

Comment: sorry for being such a pain, but are you referring to the ID for each LastName in the LastName list? do you mind giving me an example in your answer :)

Comment: I've updated my question, please take a look, I've also added the hiddenfor (updated in my code snippet for the edit view) - thank you for the update, but is it possible to do this without updating the FirstName property in the same view, I need to update them separately due to work requirement, I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: I think the new exception is because I forgot that once you transitioned to using the whole employee rather than just the names, you need to ensure that the EmployeeId and FirstName properties are present in the form. See the extra detail now in my answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: I see... so if I just want to be able to edit the LastName separate, I should not return an entire employee object but just a list of LastNames?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62706/discussion-between-josh-gallagher-and-abdul-ahmad).